Roof pipe vent leak into wall
I was on my roof a couple of days ago seeing if there was tile damage after a hail storm and I noticed on one of the pipes that the pipe flashing was old and cracking and able to let in rain (Pic 1). I fixed the flushing to stop the leak, then I went up into my attic to see if any water came in and I saw that it was slightly damp on the wood where the pipe enters the wall from above (Pic 2a & 2b). The wall that it enters is a small section of wall that divides our living room from the kitchen (3a & 3b). As you can see there is a little bit of line cracks in the ceiling, but those have been there for many years, so I don't attribute that to water damage. What would need to be done to get any potential water/moisture out of the wall?






Slightly damp, just time should work, once the leak is fixed.  More than damp would require air flow(holes, fans, maybe removing of wet stuff(drywall, insulation).

I can't see your Google Drive files. Please embed them directly into your post or use a proper image host.

Are you asking how to repair the roof flashing or how to dry out the wall of existing moisture? Please revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

I repaired the leak in the roof, so that is no longer a problem. What I'm worried about is if I need to cut into my wall or not because of the moisture that got down in there. But I think I'm going to try what crip659 said and Just drill a hole or two from the top and see if it can dry itself out.

The photos tell me that there should be enough air circulation there to allow things to simply dry out on their own.
